# Largest determinant possible of n by n matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If each entry of a three by three matrix can either be a 0 or a 5, what is the largest determinant possible?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and a lot fewer down votes, if you supply some context for your questions.  What have you done so far, and where are are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Consider your matrix as a binary array with nine entries but instead of $1$ you have $5$. This is a discrete problem. So simply you can write a computer code that produce whole its $2^9=512$ matrices which can be produce by $0 , 5$ and compare their determinants. In order to write the code you can produce $000000000-000000001-000000010-...$ change the value of $1$ by $5$ and separate these array as $3$ rows of the matrix. for example for the $000000001$ we have the matrix:
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
By doing this whole of the possible value of the matrix will be produced. in each step calculate the determinant of the matrix and save these in a vector. at the end find the maximum of the vector and the step(s) it has happened and reproduce the matrix. By doing this you will find that the maximum is $$max=250$$ which happen at three matrices: 
$$
\begin{matrix}
0 & 5 & 5 \\
5 & 0 & 5 \\
5 & 5 & 0 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
$$
\begin{matrix}
5 & 0 & 5 \\
5 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 5 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
$$
\begin{matrix}
5 & 5 & 0 \\
0 & 5 & 5 \\
5 & 0 & 5 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
Here you can see the matlab code:
clear;clc;$                                                                      $
s=zeros(1,512);
for i=0:511
a=dec2base(i,2);
a=double(a)-48*ones(1,length(a));
for j=1:8
if length(a)<9
a=[0 a];
end
end
B=[a(1:3);a(4:6);a(7:9)];
for k=1:3
for l=1:3
if B(k,l)==1
B(k,l)=5;
end
end
end
s(i+1)=det(B);
end
MAX=max(s)
Ja=find(s==MAX);
i=Ja(1)-1;
a=dec2base(i,2);
a=double(a)-48*ones(1,length(a));
for j=1:8
if length(a)<9
a=[0 a];
end
end
B=[a(1:3);a(4:6);a(7:9)];
for k=1:3
for l=1:3
if B(k,l)==1
B(k,l)=5;
end
end
end
B
i=Ja(2)-1;
a=dec2base(i,2);
a=double(a)-48*ones(1,length(a));
for j=1:8
if length(a)<9
a=[0 a];
end
end
B=[a(1:3);a(4:6);a(7:9)];
for k=1:3
for l=1:3
if B(k,l)==1
B(k,l)=5;
end
end
end
B
i=Ja(3)-1;
a=dec2base(i,2);
a=double(a)-48*ones(1,length(a));
for j=1:8
if length(a)<9
a=[0 a];
end
end
B=[a(1:3);a(4:6);a(7:9)];
for k=1:3
for l=1:3
if B(k,l)==1
B(k,l)=5;
end
end
end
B